# Numpy: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, list, numpy

I've been trying to use numpy on Python to plot some data. However I'm getting an error I don't understand:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

And this is the line supposed to cause the error (the third line):

```
def T(z):
for i in range(3):
    if (z <= z_tbl[i+1]):
        return T0_tbl[i]+a_tbl[i]*(z-z_tbl[i])
return 0
```

Those lists are just some lists of integers, and z is an integer too

How can i fix it?

Comment: What's ``z`` and ``z_tbl``?

Comment: z_tbl=[0,11000,20000,32000,47000] and z is an integer

Comment: related?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Answer (score 5):

Either `z` or `z_tbl[i+1]` is a numpy array.  For numpy arrays, rich comparisons (`==`, `<=`, `>=`, ...) return another (boolean) numpy array.

`bool` on a numpy array will give you the exception that you are seeing:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a == 1
array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> bool(a == 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Numpy is trying to tell you what to do:

```
>>> (a == 1).any()  # at least one element is true?
True
>>> (a == 1).all()  # all of the elements are true?
False
```

Comment: So how is that my z_tbl is a numpy array? I just don't understand why the comparison returns another array. It should return a boolean, shoudln't it?

Answer (score 0):

For the if condition use this

```
if (z <= z_tbl.item(i+1)):
```