# Python: Finding a numpy array in a list of numpy arrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, valueerror

I have a list of 50 numpy arrays called *vectors*:

```
[array([0.1, 0.8, 0.03, 1.5], dtype=float32), array([1.2, 0.3, 0.1], dtype=float32), .......]
```

I also have a smaller list (*means*) of 10 numpy arrays, all of which are from the bigger list above. I want to loop though each array in *means* and find its position in *vectors*.

So when I do this:

```
for c in means:
        print(vectors.index(c))
```

I get the error:

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I've gone through various SO questions and I know why I'm getting this error, but I can't find a solution. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960830/python-list-of-numpy-arrays-cant-do-index

Comment: `vectors` is a list; `vectors.index` does `v==c` for all elements until this test is `True`.  But with array elements `v==c` returns a boolean array, a `True/False` value for each element of  `v`.  That's the meaning of the ValueError - many boolean values in a context that expects just one.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is converting to a list.

```
vectors = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]], np.int32)

print vectors.tolist().index([1,2,3])
```

This will return index `0`, because `[1,2,3]` can be found in index `0` of `vectors`

Th example above is a 2d Numpy array, however you seem to have a list of numpy arrays,

so I would convert it to a list of lists this way:

```
vectors = [arr.tolist() for arr in vectors]
```

Do the same for means:

```
means = [arr.tolist() for arr in means]
```

Now we are working with two lists of lists:

So your original 'for loop' will work:

```
for c in means:
    print(vectors.index(c))
```

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. Do you know how I would convert vectors into that format?

Comment: I edited the answer for the correct conversion, let me know if this solution works for you